# I found @RecentlyNonNull in LocationResult that contradicts the code, which should I trust?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm calling the `LocationResult.extractResult` method that seems to be implemented as follows (according to IntelliJ's "go to declaration"):

```
@RecentlyNonNull
public static LocationResult extractResult(@RecentlyNonNull Intent var0) {
    return !hasResult(var0) ? null : (LocationResult)var0.getParcelableExtra("com.google.android.gms.location.EXTRA_LOCATION_RESULT");
}
```

It's hard to believe this code will never return `null`. Should I trust the annotation, or the common sense that the "then" branch of the conditional operator may sometimes be selected? The consequence of an NPE from this would probably be an application crash.

Since I'm using this from Kotlin, it of course complains that I'm making a redundant null check.

Comment: I'd imagine this could differ at runtime if calling code outside this library to an OS class?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, as the system does return `null` even on latest Android devices.

I dealt with it by suppressing the warning:

```java
// it could be null on some devices, do not remove this annotation
@Suppress("SENSELESS_COMPARISON")
```